# Before-Save flow query limits

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, query, governorlimits, limits

Since one of our main triggers has too many related processes, we are almost reaching the query limits. We have the idea to move some tasks executed in the before update context to a Before-save flow. In that way, we will be able to have more capacity in our trigger.
The main question is if this approach will really accomplish our necessity, I made a little test creating a before-save flow which is in charge of bringing some related records through the 'Get Record function' to verify if the number of SOQL is being increased. Instead of that, I'm noticing that the flow is running in a different transaction than the trigger does (actually it happens before the trigger) and the number of SOQL is the same. If that's the case, the approach will be ok, but I wanted to confirm if the limits are independent and if there's some documentation that I can rely on

[image]

In the picture you can see that updating the record creates two log transactions, The initial one for the flow and the other one for the trigger.
If I look for the number of queries used in the trigger log, I have the same number I had before implementing the flow, just 3.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: the before-save flow executes before the triggers as per [Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) - but they run in the same transaction.

Comment: Hello @cropredy the thing is that the developer console shows two different log transactions, also, I don't see that the number of SOQL is being increased

Comment: are you executing the trigger via the UX?  you may have other components on the screen that execute their own transactions. Use anon apex to insert a record

Comment: The apex trigger and flow will be executed in the same transaction and the governor’s limits will apply to the transaction. I don’t know why you see to get a different result based on your inspection. If you do a scheduled path in your record-triggered flow and enter 0 wat, that should give you a separate trx.